# NEO4J Find continual route by time

Tags: neo4j, routes

I have 40 station, identified by ID, then a I have about 30k relations between this station, realation has time property (arrival a departure time and name of line).
I need find route between station A and B, but with specific time range.
For example:

between station A and C is not direct route, you must use 
A -> B -> C = means id: 1 -> 2 -> 3

I am using this query:

```
MATCH p=(s1:L2Station{id:1})-[r:RIDE*]->(s2:L2Station{id:3}) WHERE ALL(x in r where x.deptime>=1438605300 AND x.deptime<=1438691700) 
WITH reduce(acc = [], route in rels(p)|
CASE 
WHEN toInt(route.arrtime) < last(extract(b in acc| b.deptime))   THEN null
WHEN length(acc) > 0  AND last(extract(a in acc| a.rid)) = route.rid THEN acc + route
ELSE acc + route 
END) as reducedRoutes
WHERE reducedRoutes is not null
return reducedRoutes, length(reducedRoutes) as len
order by len;
```

but this query a took about 8minutes :(

If I use this query:

```
MATCH p=(s1:L2Station{id:1})-[r:RIDE]->(s2:L2Station{id:3}) WHERE r.deptime>1438732800 AND r.deptime<1438819200 
....
```

returns nothing. I am able get only station with direct route.

Can anybody help me?

Thanks

Ondra

Comment: especialy I need filter property of relationship by range value (since/until). like 
`MATCH p=(s1:L2Station{id:1})-[r:RIDE*{deptime>since AND deptime < until}]->(s2:L2Station{id:3})`

Answer (score 0):

You are probably seeing the impact of attempting to match with an unbounded path length: `[r:RIDE*]`. Logically, this forces neo4j to follow *every possible path* that starts at station 1, to see which one ends at station 2. Probably only a few of the attempted paths will ultimately match, but neo4j is forced to follow every path to the bitter end.

If possible, you should try putting an upper bound on the path length. For example, to match paths up to length 3: `[r:RIDE*..3]`.